# adding reference to thinktecture.identityserver.3 causes This type has no accessible object constructors error in existing code

Tags: f#, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I'm attempting to host an openid connect identity server in a F# wep api project, I'm using the [F# MVC templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae8dec-d11a-4ac9-974e-be0fdadec71b) and the pre-release package of [identity server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3)

When I create either of the Katana based web api projects and subsequently add the thinktecture.identityserver.v3 package the compile fails at the line

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

with the error "this type has no accessible object constructors" with the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver underlined

At that point I have not changed any of the code  - just added the package

I have v1.13 of the vsix installed and this happens in both VS2013 and 2015 preview

I'm not sure whether this is an issue with the template, the package I added or f# in general? - any pointers on how to diagnose or where to report would be much appreciated

The same happens if I manually add a reference to the identity server assembly but I could not replicate when adding other nuget packages - how would adding a reference somehow mask the constructor from the newtonsoft type?

It only appears to affect that type - if I comment out that line the code compiles

full listing of startup.fs

```
namespace FSharpWeb1

open Owin
open Microsoft.Owin
open System
open System.Net.Http
open System.Web
open System.Web.Http
open System.Web.Http.Owin

[<Sealed>]
type Startup() =

    static member RegisterWebApi(config: HttpConfiguration) =
        // Configure routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        // Configure serialization
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer <- true
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

        // Additional Web API settings

    member __.Configuration(builder: IAppBuilder) =
        let config = new HttpConfiguration()
        Startup.RegisterWebApi(config)
        builder.UseWebApi(config) |> ignore
```

UPDATE 1

Just for fun I repeated a similar exercise in Xamarin studio with the same results - as soon as the ref to identity server is added then it breaks

I also tried updating the version of newtonsoft to the latest stable and that didn't help

UPDATE 2

Turns out the identity server project uses ILMerge to merge in dependencies such as the newtonsoft dll - If I build the identity server core dll without using ILMerge and reference that then the problem does not occur - so is this an F# issue or with ILMerge hiding constructor?